# How to build and debug spark from IDE(preferrably Eclipse)?

Tags: apache-spark

I wanted to contribute to spark.

I cloned the git repository locally. Please suggest how to setup spark first and then run a hello world over it from IDE itself.

Comment: What do you mean by set up Spark ? does that mean you want to setup the IDE environment ?

Comment: @Ashrith, yes i want to setup IDE through which i can run and debug spark code(not the applicatoins running on it)

Answer (score 1):

For importing/building Spark in IntelliJ or Eclipse follow this [guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPARK/Useful+Developer+Tools#UsefulDeveloperTools-IDESetup).

If you are interested in contributing to Spark visit this wiki page for more information:

- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPARK/Contributing+to+Spark

Comment: Thanks @Yijie for the details. What i need is more specific. What i have done till now is: I have cloned the spark git repository locally. Downloaded all their MVN dependencies. Now let's say i import all the spark projects into my workspace. Which launcher to run? How to write a Hello World on top of it?

Comment: Thanks @Yijie for the details. What i need is more specific. What i have done till now is: I have cloned the spark git repository locally. Downloaded all their MVN dependencies. Now let's say i import all the spark projects into my workspace. Which launcher to run? How to write a Hello World on top of it?

Comment: Could you elaborate on this 'Which launcher to run?' .

Comment: @techagrammer, Ashrith wrote this answer, I just reordered it :)

Comment: @YijieShen, normally in eclipse we have launcher files with (.launch) to start the application. There we can configure vmarguments and other stuff. What i want to know is even after importing all the projects, how to run spark

Comment: @techagrammer, Sorry man, I don't know how to cope with the `.launch` staff, I use Intellij IDEA to debug and test Spark source code. If you'd like to move to Intellij IDEA .....

Answer (score 1):

I assume you already have the latest release of Scala IDE (4.0 at this point) from [scala-ide.org](http://www.scala-ide.org).

- export projects using `sbt eclipse`, I guess you figured that out already.
- import all projects in your workspace (`Import Existing projects`)

  - you will probably see a number of errors related to "cross-compiled libraries"

If you want to develop on Scala 2.10, you need to configure a Scala installation for the exact Scala version that’s used to compile Spark. At the time of this writing that is Scala 2.10.4.

- you can do that in `Eclipse Preferences -> Scala -> Installations` by pointing to the `lib/` directory of your Scala 2.10.4 distribution.
- select all Spark projects and right-click, choose `Scala -> Set Scala Installation` and point to the 2.10.4 installation. This should clear all errors about invalid cross-compiled libraries.
- a clean build should succeed.

You can easily find examples on getting started with Spark, for example [here](https://spark.apache.org/examples.html). You can run a Spark app using `right-click -> Run As Scala Application`.